# How do I use Selenium Webdriver to find elements in a single page site with C#?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I need some help please. I am trying to write a webdriver C# code that checks for elements in a site. However the site is a single page website with embedded form, its contents changes after you click Next?

So basically when I click Next the new form appears and I want to do a validation to see if new elements in the new form appear. Currently this is how I am doing the validation

```
 private By labelPageHeader = By.XPath("//form[1]/div[4]/label[text()='Welcome to the second form']");

    public bool IsNewForm()
    {
        return Elements.CheckElementIsVisible(_driver, labelPageHeader );
    }
```

When I do that  I get error:

> Could not load page within the designated timeout period

That usually works when I am not working in a single page site.

This is the HTML. I am trying to hit the  id="alligator" inside the form

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="./report-fraud-form.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1" onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();" id="form1">

                            <div id="Step3" class="step">
                                <div id="alligator" class="input">

                                    <label for="alligator">Welcome to the second form
                                        <abbr title="This field is required">*</abbr></label>                                   

                                </div>
                                <input type="hidden" class="link" value="Step4" />
                            </div>
                            <!-- step3 ends -->
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far, that will make it easier for use to help you.

Comment: @BreaksSoftware Done. Thank you for taking a look.

Answer (score 0):

Your XPath looks bad.  since "id" attributes are provided, best practice is to use those.  The path worked for me given that snippet of HTML:

```
//form[@id='form1']//div[@id='alligator']/label
```

If you're really looking for that input in the form:

```
//form[@id='form1']//div[@id='alligator']/following-sibling::input
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @BreaksSoftware! I tried the xpath you provided and I noticed two things, when I run the test with or without debugger, it fails but when I put a breakpoint in the "IsNewForm" method and use f11 to step into it, the element gets hit and the test pass. One other thing I think may be the issue is that the site contains javascripts. Is there a different way to check if Element is visible using javascript?

Comment: Your comment implies that there is a delay before the form displays.  I don't know C#, so I can't tell you how to do it, but it sounds like you need to have an explicit wait for the form to appear using a WebDriverWait() call, then the check for visibility should succeed.

Comment: I have tried that and it still fails. I did this: IWait<IWebDriver> wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3.00));
            IWebElement element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(labelPageHeader ));

Comment: I still need help with this if anyone wants to assist

Comment: are you sure that your script is actually taking the action to open the form in the first place?  if you watch the browser while in debug, do you see the form open?

Comment: I thought that could be the issue but it is not. When I switch the driver to Chrome or even Firefox, that particular step passed. so the issue is only occurring when I run my test on IE

Comment: are you using the synchronized versions of Selenium, the webdriver for IE, and the IE browser?  It's beginning to smell like an IE web driver bug.
I suppose you could also double check that the path is the same in IE vs Chrome or FF?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "the synchronized versions of Selenium, the webdriver for IE, and the IE browser". But ironically IE is the browser I have the path setup in the environment variable.

Comment: Only certain versions of the webdriver for IE will work with specific versions of IE.  Likewise, the webdriver will have dependency on certain version of Selenium.  You want to make sure that you're using the versions that all work together.

Comment: this may sound like a stupid question, but how do I check whether the version of Selenium, the IEDriver and IE itself are compatible with one another?

Comment: Never mind. I think I have track this issue down to IE 11 settings. I am now looking for a workaround. Thanks for your response.